# VB ByRef does not work

Tags: vb.net, pass-by-reference

Hello this site is my nr1 code inspiration, now I have a problem myselve that I can't fix.

I have a module CommCtrl that contains a Tagcollection
In another class I made a reference to this collection
If I fill the reference with items, The items are only added
in this class, not in the CommCtrl class. 
I don't understand why the reference is not working.

```
Public Module CommCtrl
   Public TagCollection As New List(Of Tag)
   Private WayPointManager As WayPointClass

   Public Sub BuildConfigData()        
       WayPointManager = New WayPointClass()
       WayPointManager.SetTagListReference(TagCollection)

       ' Count items in Tagcollection here is 0 items 
       call WayPointManager.FillTags
       ' Count items in Tagcollection here is still 0 items??
   End Sub

End module  


Public Class WayPointClass

    Private TagListReference As List(Of Tag)

    Public Sub SetTagListReference(ByRef TagList As List(Of Tag))
        TagListReference = TagList
    End Sub 

    Public Function FillTags() As Boolean
        TagListReference = XmlBuddy.Deserialize(reader)    ' Fill Up the taglist
        ' Count items in TagListReference here is 100 items 
    End Function
 End Class
```

Comment: Indeed, that's not what ByRef does.  Make TagListReference a property instead so you can access it after the FillTags call.  Or give FillTags a ByRef argument so it can return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method's parameter the with `ByRef` keyword can only take place if the parameter appears on the left hand side of an assignment.

```
sub modify(byref p as integer)
    p = 1 ' byref param on the LHS of an assignment
end sub

dim a as int = 0
call modify(a)
console.writeline(a) ' prints 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand how this translates to my code, can you give me an example or explenation.

Answer (score 3):

ByRef works fine. What is happening is that:

When you firstly call your `WayPointClass.SetTagListReference`method, you are setting your `TagListReference` field to point to the incoming `List(of Tag)` parameter ( in your example this will be `CommCtrl.TagCollection`).

But when you call `WayPointClass.SetTags`, you are not setting the value of the original List (`CommCtrl.TagCollection`) as you suppose, you are actually changing `TagListReference` to point to a new List, and there is no link to the original `CommCtrl.TagCollection`.

To put it another way, initially you are pointing `TagListReference` (A) to `TagCollection` (B), i.e. A -> B. But then you are making A -> C (the result of `XmlBuddy.Deserialize(reader)`), and B is unchanged.

As Hans Passant says, you can avoid this by passing `CommCtrl.TagCollection` into the `FillTags' method so then you are definitely modifying that list.

Comment: Thanx for the clear explenation. This worked, and even better I now know why it didn't.